# Dynamic prompts in SAS

Tags: stored-procedures, sas

I'm trying to build some dynamic prompts with a stored procedure in SAS EG that are dynamic but not cascading (by that I mean that selecting a value will filter every other prompt, instead of having to answer prompts in a particular order).

Is there any way to do this without resorting to Javascript? All the documentation I've found points to the dependencies tab and it doesn't seem to have that capability.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what that might work/look like?  What is prompt 1 asking, what is being filtered, what is prompt 2 based on/asking?

Comment: For example: If I have two variables listing medical clinic locations and physician names, I want the user to be able to either input physician names first and have that restrict the clinics that show up under the clinic prompt, or have them select clinic first and have that limit physician names. The way it's set up under dependencies you HAVE to have it filter in a particular direction (right now it's Clinic -> physician)

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the built in promoting framework. I think the prompts always go in order, with later prompts dependent on earlier prompts.